# IActionResult misunderstanding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I just downloaded **music store** (microsoft sample projct) source code that based on ASP.NET 5. I don't understand there why developers from Microsoft use IActionResult interface as a return type in controllers.

**What is a reason of IActionResult interface usage?** Why don't just use ActionResult type.

[image]

Comment: what's wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just trying to figure out why they don't use ActionResult type instead..

Comment: But why should they do that? As in the answer mentioned, returning an interface provides more flexibility and it is a common pattern by the way

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See this post about `IActionResult` vs. `ActionResult`: http://forums.asp.net/post/5980446.aspx

`IActionResult` allows a wider range of return types, including any custom code that implements the `IActionResult` interface.  `ActionResult` is limited only to those classes which extend the `ActionResult` abstract class (which you could also do with custom code, but using an interface allows for something like multiple inheritance, while extending a class does not).

Comment: While this may answer the question link only answers are discouraged. Please at least provide a summary of the information in the link.

Comment: @R.Salisbury I know this is an old post, but according to the link you provided, the author gives the impression that you can only access all results listed (`ContentResult`, `JsonResult` etc.) if you use the interface implementation, `IActionResult`. I don't know if any changes has been made since 2015, but at this moment it is entirely possible to access all the results listed simply by using `ActionResult`. So it seems to me, that there is no advantage at all to using the interface. Can you confirm or deny this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using interfaces as parameters will allow you to use dependency injection to obtain its dependencies and those  dependencies can be replaced with mock implementations when testing which implement those interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

`IActionResult` has more return types than `ActionResult`. For ex: If you want to return `HttpNotFound` you have to use IActionResult return type.

Comment: There is no such thing in Asp.Net Core as `HttpNotFound`, there is `NotFoundResult` that is still inherit the form ActionResult indirectly, which mean you CAN use ActionResult as a return type.